# Build Error on last '}' of a VC++ CLR project

Tags: c++, user-interface, clr, intellisense

I'm working on a project in CLR for my Capstone in school and I discovered it to be simple to build a UI. I was creating a button that would run a simple group of statements that would set certain criteria to values and would put up an error if you put an incorrect value into the boxes.

That is merely context to the problem. Their are 6 text boxes for input and the code is all the same except variable names. So I had 3 working and it would build perfectly fine. Then after I copied and pasted the last three this error appeared with more that I have worked out.

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '}' c:\users\ibuypower\desktop\jjba-rpg character builder\jjba-rpg character builder\MyForm.h   1612    1   JJBA-RPG character builder
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\ibuypower\desktop\jjba-rpg character builder\jjba-rpg character builder\MyForm.h   1612    1   JJBA-RPG character builder
Error   3   IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\Users\iBUYPOWER\Desktop\JJBA-RPG character builder\JJBA-RPG character builder\MyForm.h   1612    1   JJBA-RPG character builder
```

It still works before I added the extra code. I would post more but my MyForm is over 1600 lines of code.

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace JJBARPGcharacterbuilder;

[System::STAThreadAttribute]

int main()
{
JJBARPGcharacterbuilder::MyForm fm;
fm.ShowDialog();

return 0;
}
```

This is my CPP file and I had to modify it a bit to remove the other errors. All three of those errors occur on the last brace of my MyForm.h file. I'm just really stumped and will gladly supply more code for context if needed.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

```
    private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         String ^ Buildpoints_text = Buildpoints->Text;
         __int32 Buildpoints_Max = System::Int32::Parse(Buildpoints_text); // Takes the maximum amount of buildpoints and submits it as a integer
         if (Buildpoints_Max > 0){
             MessageBox::Show("Your buildpoints are " + Buildpoints_Max);
         }
         else{
             MessageBox::Show("Please input a maximum buildpoint value.");
         }
}

private: System::Void button3_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, 
System::EventArgs^  e) {
         String ^ Potential_letter = Potential_input->Text;
         int Potential_value;
             if (Potential_letter == "A"){
                 Potential_value = 3;
             }
             else if (Potential_letter == "B"){
                 Potential_value = 2;
             }
             else if (Potential_letter == "C"){
                 Potential_value = 1;
             }
             else if (Potential_letter == "D"){
                 Potential_value = 0;
             }
             else if (Potential_letter == "E"){
                 Potential_value = -1;
             }
             else {
                 MessageBox::Show("Incorrect Potential value.");
             }
    };
};
}
} //Error occurs here. It says it requires a semi-colon before. I add one and no change.
```

Comment: Ok. I'll bite. Why didn't you include the header file that is actually *reporting the error* in your question? Stripped down, of course. (your header is 1800 lines long??) Fwiw, if code works prior to your last edits, and doesn't after, odds are.. you know.

Comment: Well to be honest I'm new to Stackoverflow so that is the first question I've asked and when I tried to copy and paste code it always pastes very... strangely

Comment: Pasting code into a *question* box in SO (note: **not** a comment; please don't put walls of code in comments): 1. past the code. 2. Select the code you just pasted. 3. Hit Ctrl-K (everything-but-mac), or Cmd-K (only mac). That's it. Review the results before posting it, but that should do it.

Comment: I posted 1 block of the mentioned event code as well as an event for a button above it.

Comment: Is the posted code anywhere *near* line 1612 of MyForm.h ? If so, it needs to be clearly marked with a comment. If not... not much we can help with. A guess: a class-closing close-brace should have a trailing `;` . If those last two `}` in your posted code close (a) the class, then (b) the namespace, the former needs to be `};`

Comment: Thanks for the guess! I have thought that as well. One of the errors mentions a "Missing ';' before '}'" and I have added one but the errors don't change which makes me scratch my head.

Comment: You put the `;` after the second-to-last `}` right ? As in, the last three characters should be `};}`. And the problem *still* happens ? The compiler is expecting either a terminating `;` or an id (which would be how you could declare an *instance* of the class, similar to `class foo {..} bar;`. You seem to want the former of those, and the posted code doesn't comply.

Comment: I did. But then I deleted the last brace and now it works. I tried that earlier and it still didn't work. So go figure I guess.

Comment: That tells me this code is somehow not in the namespace. Perhaps it (the namespace) was closed earlier in the source file. Visual C++ has a nie feature of finding matching braces. Google it. It's a handy feature worth learning. Best of luck.